# 320 photosource / photoviewer with json

Tags: iphone, three20

I've managed to edit the TTTwitter sample project so it can parse my JSON and slap it into an array which i can read from.

But I'm struggling to think how i would insert this into the TTCatalog to use with photosource.m and photoviewer.m

The part which i need is below

`- (void)load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more {`

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:kTwitterSearchFeedFormat2, @"searchPARAM"];

TTURLRequest* request = [TTURLRequest
                         requestWithURL: url
                         delegate: self];

request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
request.cacheExpirationAge = TT_CACHE_EXPIRATION_AGE_NEVER;
TTURLJSONResponse* response = [[TTURLJSONResponse alloc] init];
request.response = response;
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(response);
[request send];
}

- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
TTURLJSONResponse* response = request.response;
TTDASSERT([response.rootObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]);
NSDictionary* feed = response.rootObject;
TTDASSERT([[feed objectForKey:@"images"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);
NSLog(@"The content of arry is%@",feed);    
NSArray* entries = [feed objectForKey:@"images"];
NSLog(@"The content of arry is%d",entries.count);    
[super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
```

}

I added this to the photosource.m file hoping i can use the array to pick out the URLS to use in photoviewer.m

How do i make it, so those 2 are actually ran when i open the photoviewer.m so i can dynamically load up the pictures.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In photoviewer.m Uncomment the below

```
[NSNull null],
```